# Java command Line compilation with multiple sources

Tags: java, command-line, compilation

I know the title doesn't fully describe my problem, but I'm not sure how else to ask this. I know there's tools to do this, but I want to understand how the compiler works in java, I wrote some very basic code and I'm able to compile them without any problems using

```
javac -sourcepath java -d ../target/dir1 java/shapes/mainclass/TestRun.java
```

in the command line, but that only works when the `packages` are in the same source directory as seen in the picture below

[image: Packages are in the same source directory]

I want to be able to compile from the command line where my `package` are in other source directories as well, please see the picture below

[image: Packages are in multiple sources]

Does anyone know how I can do this ? I tried modifying the command line to

`javac -sourcepath java -d ../target/ java/dir1/shapes/mainclass/TestRun.java` but this results in the following error

```
java\dir1\shapes\mainclass\TestRun.java:3: error: package shapes.classes does not exist
import shapes.classes.*;
^
java\dir1\shapes\mainclass\TestRun.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                ShapeMain circle = new Circle(5);
                ^
  symbol:   class ShapeMain
  location: class TestRun
java\dir1\shapes\mainclass\TestRun.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                ShapeMain circle = new Circle(5);
                                       ^
  symbol:   class Circle
  location: class TestRun
java\dir1\shapes\mainclass\TestRun.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                ShapeMain rectangle = new Rectangle(8, 9.9);
                ^
  symbol:   class ShapeMain
  location: class TestRun
java\dir1\shapes\mainclass\TestRun.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
                ShapeMain rectangle = new Rectangle(8, 9.9);
                                          ^
  symbol:   class Rectangle
  location: class TestRun
java\dir1\shapes\mainclass\TestRun.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                ShapeMain triangle = new Triangle(10, 4.5);
                ^
  symbol:   class ShapeMain
  location: class TestRun
java\dir1\shapes\mainclass\TestRun.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
                ShapeMain triangle = new Triangle(10, 4.5);
                                         ^
  symbol:   class Triangle
  location: class TestRun
7 errors
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: An alternative would be to define two different projects.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution, you should use `javac -sourcepath java/dir1;java/dir2 -d ../target/dir1 java/dir1/shapes/mainclass/TestRun.java`

notice that on the `-sourcepath` its not `-sourcepath java` but its `-sourcepath java/dir1;java/dir2`, its specifying where the `.java` classes are in each directory

Answer (score 0):

Use -d command line parameter with javac to tell it what directory you'd like to store the compiled class files in. After complication run the program, using java -cp

```
javac -d some/directory javaprogram.java
```

java - cp some/directory javaprogram

Answer (score 0):

You should be *in* the`src/java` directory, and adjust your commands accordingly.

Comment: I was able to achieve my goal from the src directory

Comment: No doubt, but this is the easy way to do it.